# Handle exception for Scala Async and Future variable, error accessing variable name outside try block

Tags: json, scala, concurrency, try-catch

```
@scala.throws[scala.Exception]  
def processQuery(searchQuery : scala.Predef.String) : scala.concurrent.Future[io.circe.Json] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

How do I declare the `searchResult` variable at line 3 so that it can be initailized inside the `try` block and can be processed if it's successful after and outside the `try` block. Or, is there any other way to handle the exception? The file containing `processQuery` function is not editable to me, it's read-only.

```
def index = Action.async{ implicit request =>
  val query = request.body.asText.get
  var searchResult : scala.concurrent.Future[io.circe.Json] = Future[io.circe.Json]  //line 3
  var jsonVal = ""
  try {
    searchResult = search.processQuery(query) 
  } catch {
    case e :Throwable =>  jsonVal = e.getMessage
  }

  searchResult onSuccess ({
    case result => jsonVal = result.toString()
  })

  searchResult.map{ result =>
    Ok(Json.parse(jsonVal))
  }    
}
```

if declared in the way it has been declared it's showing compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would using the `recover` method help you? I also suggest to avoid `var` and use a more functional approach if possible. In my world (and play Json library), I would hope to get to something like:

```
def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
  processQuery(request.body.asText.get).map { json =>
    Ok(Json.obj("success" -> true, "result" -> json))
  }.recover {
    case e: Throwable => Ok(Json.obj("success" -> false, "message" -> e.getMessage))
  }
}
```

I guess it may be necessary to put the code in another whole `try` `catch`:

```
try {
  processQuery....
  ...
} catch { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether I have use try catch block But I'm having difficulty resolving dependencies. If I add import io.circe.Json , then there is synrax error at Json.obj(cannot resolve symbol Json), whereas if I comment out the import and instead use import play.api.libs.Json, the previous error is not there but I'm getting error in "result" -> Json (found : (String, Json) eequired :(String, Json.JsValueWrapper))

Comment: Json.obj is just my (play) way of creating a Json object. I don't know the iocirce library so I can't tell you how to do that, but there will be a way.

Answer (score 0):

I have here a way to validate on the incoming JSON and fold on the result of the validation:

```
def returnToNormalPowerPlant(id: Int) = Action.async(parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
    request.body.validate[ReturnToNormalCommand].fold(
      errors => {
        Future.successful{
          BadRequest(
            Json.obj("status" -> "error", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors))
          )
        }
      },
      returnToNormalCommand => {
        actorFor(id) flatMap {
          case None =>
            Future.successful {
              NotFound(s"HTTP 404 :: PowerPlant with ID $id not found")
            }
          case Some(actorRef) =>
            sendCommand(actorRef, id, returnToNormalCommand)
        }
      }
    )
  }
```